# Я получаю максимальную амплитуду звука, как можно получить с помощью этого децибелы?

Tags: java, android, аудио

```
double DB = 20*Math.log10(finalAmplitude/1.0);
((TextView)(findViewById(R.id.TVDb))).setText(DB + " Дб");
```

Я пробовал использовать формулу которую нашёл в интернете, но значения, что я получаю определенно не верны. Как я могу узнать громкость звука в децибелах?

Comment: Сделал, извиняюсь

Comment: Ну формула правильная. Почему думаете что результат неверный?

Comment: периодически явно большие числа и -infinity

Comment: Так значит значение амплитуда неверное. Или не совсем амплитуды.

Comment: Вероятно, надо проверить, спасибо